# How do I format a string value as an actual string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Consider this dict:

```
d = {
   value_1 = 'hello',
   value_2 = False,
   value_3 = 29
}
```

I want to write these vars in a file like this:

```
value_1 = 'hello'
value_2 = False
value_3 = 29
```

I've tried:

```
f.write(
    "\n".join(
        [
            "{key} = {value}".format(**dict(key=k, value=v))
            for k, v in d.items()
        ]
    )
)
```

But the output is

```
value_1 = hello  # not a string
value_2 = False
value_3 = 29
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use should use the `repr` representation of the values. Use `{!r}` in string formatting for that:

```
>>> x = 'hello'
>>> print x
hello
>>> print repr(x)
'hello'
>>> print '{!r}'.format(x)
'hello'
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> c = StringIO()
>>> d = {
...    'value_1' : 'hello',
...    'value_2' : False,
...    'value_3' : 29
... }
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     c.write("{} = {!r}\n".format(k, v))
...
>>> c.seek(0)     
>>> print c.read()
value_1 = 'hello'
value_3 = 29
value_2 = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `repr`. Also `**dict(…)` is silly.

```
"{key} = {value}".format(key=k, value=repr(v))
```